# Slow response time getting json data from Flask application from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, d3.js, flask

I have a Flask application that takes requests from javascript, queries a database, then sends the data back to be visualized using D3.js. Calls to the database return rougly 5mb of data. I am getting very slow response times (roughly 20 seconds) between when the response is sent from flask until when it has finished loading into a javascript variable in d3.

Any idea why it is so slow to get data sent between my d3 and Flask?

If I simply print the json string to a blank page in the browser the response is nearly instantaneous. I get similar (fast) performance if I just write the json string to a static file then load that with d3. I am fairly certain the problem is simply piping the data directly through to d3. I have also tried calling flask using `$.getJSON` in a query and the results are similarly slow. Why is Flask slow at returning the json string but not just rendering it to the browser?

In D3 I call:

```
d3.json("/test", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Example Flask call

```
@app.route('/test')
def get_json_object():
    a = {....some large dictionary....}
    return jsonify(**a)
```

Comment: Its almost certainly the js side that is slowing it down. Flask returns the same json regardless of where its going afterwards.  Have you tried a simple ajax call (i.e. `$.get`) to compare performance?  And perhaps run the js through a debugger or have a look at network monitor in firefox

Comment: Yes I tried just making a straight get call using JQuery and the performance is still just as slow. When I run the profiler it says that 90% of the 20 second run cycle is just 'idle' as if the javascript is waiting for data.

Comment: But loading the full URL (i.e. `www.example.com/test') in the browser is fast?  How about try curl for comparison?

Comment: So downloading the file using wget takes longer than the $.get request, but if I just go to the full URL the json text string is rendered in the browser almost immediately.  Moreover, if I have Flask print the json string to the console I see it there far before the javascript gets a response.  It might be just a slow connection, but given that I can load from a static file (rather then a get request) almost instantly, I really think there is something either with how Flask sends responses or who the javascript is getting them.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could your browser be caching the page?  So going to the URL in your browser uses a cached result so it loads instantaneously, but wget or ajax gets it from flask?

Comment: I think the problem was, indeed, that I was caching the page when I did things other ways.  Thanks for the help!